# iOS code coverage broken in Xcode 4.5?

Tags: ios, code-coverage, xcode4.5

I'm trying to set up code coverage in Xcode 4.5. To do so, I turned on Generate Test Coverage Files and Instrument Program Flow for debug setting. According to http://meandmark.com/blog/2012/08/xcode-4-generating-code-coverage-files-with-llvm/ that's all you need. However, now the linker complains that it can't find:

- _llvm_gcda_emit_arcs
- _llvm_gcda_emit_function
- _llvm_gcda_end_file
- _llvm_gcda_increment_indirect_counter
- _llvm_gcda_start_file

I tried to find libprofile_rt.dylib, but it doesn't seem to exist anymore. What else is needed to generate code coverage files?

Comment: LLVM code coverage is currently available only for Mac OS X, not iOS.

Comment: It is available for iOS. Also the instruction in the blog entry is not complete. It's missing creating a testing target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also ran into these linker errors. I saw the errors using Xcode 4.2 and 4.3. I'm not sure if they still are there in 4.5.

To solve it I added [this file](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/runtime/libprofile/GCDAProfiling.c) from the llvm project to my unit test code project. To get it to build on my Mac I deleted the win32 and sys includes and replaced the `#include "llvm/Support/DataTypes.h"` include with `#include "stdint.h"`.

Comment: Hi, I still have this problem..And I'm trying to fix it. I could not find the exact same file as you did, but I got this file called: GCOVProfiling.cpp. I think they have the same functionality. The problem is that it has so many imports of other files in the llvm project. What should I do with all the imports? Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Under the target build setting (be sure to select all)

Set:

- Apple LLVM complier

  - Instrument Program Flow: YES
  - Generate Test Coverage Files: YES

Comment: This is a perfectly correct answer. I have just confirmed that on Xcode 4.5.1. You just need to set these settings for a testing target.

You can create a target for testing:
File -> New -> Target  
Then select iOS | Other | Cocoa Touch Unit Testing Bundle

Additionally you might need to set Generate Profiling Code: YES to get gcda files generated. That was the only problem that I have recently encountered. There should be no link errors.

Comment: I have the same problem. gcno files are there but no gcda files. I did set them for all build configurations and set Generate Profiling Code to YES but still, no gcda files.

Comment: I have both *.gcno and *.gcda files in the output with these options set to YES.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me after I included Google Analytics SDK in my code (using Xcode 5). Can you please expelain what does it do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The unit tests must pass in order for gcda files to be generated.